# How would you totally isolate a laptop from any network?

Tags: hardware

I've been thinking hard about that Faraday's cage, but what if someone needed to use the computer ? Also, the laptop wouldn't be trusty, so you never know exactly what's inside, what could emit information through any network. This would be really helpful in case of audit works, to prevent industrial spying for example.

Comment: turn it off? It's unclear what you want to do and why and what threats you want to counter

Comment: The laptop would be in use, and the major threat would be data steal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in a locked room in the basement, remove the hardware that it could use to attach to a network (cat-5 cable, wifi antenna, use a UPS that isolates from mains). Now you have to limit the users ability to attach to some network through the exposed UI, I'd suggest a guard in a separate users room as shown in my previous answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/155141/8072).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. It seems doable in limited time, that's the best solution.